# How can i set Lotus Notes as the default mail program?

Tags: 11.10, default, notes

What should i write in the: X-scheme-handler/mailto=                      ?
I have Lotus Notes 8.5.2.
It doesnt work if i just trying to change it from System Settings==>Default applications.
It doesnt give the option to add Notes as a default but the calendat is ok and been set automaticly since i installed Notes.

Maybe i just need to know the right name of the application ant put it in:

X-scheme-handler/mailto=

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to the end of `/usr/share/applications/LotusNotes8.5.desktop`, ie:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/LotusNotes8.5.desktop) and save the file:
```

> MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;x-scheme-handler/mailto;
>   TargetEnvironment=Messaging Menu;Unity

Next, run the following command:

```
sudo update-desktop-database -q
```

Go to *System Settings* > *System Info* and click on **Default Applications**. Lotus Notes 8.5 should now show up as an mail application option.

Comment: @MAX you should then accept it as an answer using the green check mark next to the up and down vote arrows.

Comment: The use of ´TargetEnvironment´ is deprecated: http://markmail.org/message/eypvnff4bieqf5bj

Answer (score 1):

Editing the /usr/shar/.../.desktop shortcut did NOT work for me (13.04 raring).

What got me farther was based on an answer to another question

1. Edit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list and add to the Default Applications section:

   ```
   x-scheme-handler/mailto=IBMNotes9.0.desktop
   ```
2. sudo update-desktop-database

Once I had done that Notes showed as already selected in the "Details" app as my default mail application. Now mailto links will open notes, **but** it does not open a new composition window.

Any ideas for fixing the last mile here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Changing %F to %U in the desktop-file fixed it for me.